# --inspect-brk node-args for hardhat js scripts

Tags: node.js, hardhat

I run a [hardhat script](https://hardhat.org/guides/scripts.html) like this:

```
npx hardhat run myscript.js
```

I'd like to be able to debug this in the Chrome inspector, but when I do

```
npx --node-arg=--inspect-brk hardhat run myscript.js
```

I get the error message "ERROR: --node-arg/-n can only be used on packages with node scripts."

Is there a way to debug hardhat scripts in Chrome without resorting to console.log?

Comment: you could try running the same command differently:
`node --inspect-brk node_modules/.bin/hardhat run myscript`